# accessing value of input field by id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose name of an id is store in a variable x (var x="big";), i was hoping to access the value of an input field whose id is big

e.g

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){

        var x="#"+$(this).attr("name"); ///works fine here
        alert($(x).value());   //hoping to get small but not working

    });


});


</script>
<input type="hidden" value="small" id="big" />
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn" name="big"/>
```

Comment: For reference the API is a great help when learning jQuery: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
$(x).value()
```

.value() is not a valid/standred jquery method. For getting the values of text-box, you should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var x="#"+$(this).attr("name"); 
        alert($(x).val()); 
    });
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RVV7C/)

Answer (score 0):

This method is `val()`:

```
alert($(x).val());
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/4rjjf/

Comment: @Don If some answer solves your problem, tap the checkmark below vote count ("accept answer").

Answer (score 0):

value is not function. change it to val();
here is demo

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/z5UVk/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){

        var x=$(this).attr("name"); ///works fine here
        alert($("#"+x).val());   //hoping to get small but not working

    });


});
```